# How to stretch / scale background images in an Android linear layout?

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, background, stretch

I need some help making a background image stretch or scale both vertically and horizontally in a linear layout. Every time I try to set the background however, it doesn't stretch the image to fit the screen. I'm not concerned about keeping the aspect ratio either.

Here's what I've got in a test xml at the moment:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
</LinearLayout>
```

Which looks like this in preview (and in the game):

[image]

If I change the layout_height to fill_parent I get a repeating background:

[image]
I'm sure the solution is extremely basic, but for some reason I'm missing it. Any help would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: The problem seems that comes up with Tablet device ... try to use a bigger image and set width and height to 'match_parent'

Comment: Wish there were more answers here.

Comment: How did you test all screens like this?

Comment: @Sami it is an option in Android Studio when you preview the xml.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what available background layout options are available for the background attribute of a layout, but you can always just put an ImageView as the first element in an outer FrameLayout with maximum width and height.  Then anything else you put into the layout will be drawn on top of this image.  And of course you can just load in a scaletype that you desire; such as fitXY perhaps for what you are trying to achieve.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/backgroundDescription"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop">
</ImageView>   
...
```

Answer (score 4):

here is important `android:scaleType` parameter with one of possible values:

- matrix
- fitXY
- fitStart
- fitCenter
- fitEnd
- center
- centerCrop
- centerInside

if you don't mind image to be croped when it is necessary (screen of different ratio than your image) and you don't want image to be deformed, I would recommend **`centerCrop`**.
if it is important that image is not cropped and you don't ind if it is skewed, than **`fitXY`** will do the job.

Hope this helped and cleared things up a bit...

Answer (score 0):

You can use scaleType with centerCrop

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/background" />
```

Comment: I think fitXY will be better in this case